# Calling a C++ class from Matlab (with memory persistance)

Tags: c++, matlab

How can I call a C++ class (.cpp and .h files) from matlab such that it would stay persistent in the memory until the use for it is done, and only then I free it?

Example:
A matlab GUI that can stay on indefinitely. On startup, the C++ class is allocated. As long as the GUI is running (even in idle mode), the class remains persistent, and awaits for the GUI to call its methods. When the user closes the GUI, the class is freed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38964-example-matlab-class-wrapper-for-a-c++-class) of how to do this on the MATLAB Central File Exchange. It's been contributed to by a few MathWorks developers, and shows how to wrap a C++ class in a MATLAB class, via a mex interface, safely, without memory leaks, whilst achieving an interface in MATLAB that is similar to the underlying C++ interface.

Comment: The link seems to be out of date.

Comment: @YuvalWeissler The whole of the File Exchange appears to be down for maintenance right now. Once it's back up, I think the link will be fine - I followed it successfully this morning.

Comment: I've seen this example. sadly, there's a fatal error when compiling the mex file, about a certain 'stdint.h' file which cannot be included. I Don't quite know how to fix it. Do you?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, I'm not a big user of mex. However I've met the author of the submission, Oliver Woodford, and he's very helpful - you might try contacting him with a question on the submission page.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you will want is to create an `Init` and `Exit` function which allocate and free the memory for the class.  When your GUI starts `Init` should be called and when you are done `Exit` should be called.  You might implement it as follows (untested, don't know how safe this method is either, don't call Init/Exit out of order either):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int a) : m_A(a) {}
private:
    int m_A;
};

MyClass* instance;

void Wrapper_Init(void)
{
    instance = new MyClass(5);
}

void Wrapper_Exit(void)
{
    delete instance;
}
```

You could then write other functions to access/manipulate the instance of `MyClass`.  This feels a bit like creating a ugly C wrapper for a nice C++ class but I don't know of a more elegant solution.

See also:
http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/783-i-have-a-c-class-how-can-i-interface-to-it-through-a-matlab-class